# How to parse HTML & replace Tags in a String using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I have a string like this (unminified here for easy reading):

```
var input='<div id="container" style="max-width: 310px;">
    <div class="popupheadermap">
        <b>YFC</b>
    </div>
    <input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tab-group" type="radio">
    <label for="tab-1">Administration</label>
    <input id="tab-2" name="tab-group" type="radio">
    <label for="tab-2">Information</label>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-1">
            <td>Id</td>
            <td class="tablerow">1252</td>
        </div>
        <div id="content-2">
            <td>Type</td>
            <td class="tablerow">Gym</td>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="EditContainer">
    <button class="editMarker" id="1252"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil editicon"></i>Edit Location</button>
</div>';
```

Using jQuery I want to replace the contents of the `EditContainer` div, so that it becomes:

```
<div id="EditContainer">
    <button id="1126_1" class="saveCancel"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o editicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Save Edit</button> 
    <button id="1126_2" class="saveCancel"><i class="fa fa-ban editicon" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Cancel Edit</button>
</div>
```

But when I use find, with `$(input).find('#EditContainer')`, I get an empty ouput.

How do I parse this string, and replace the contents of the `EditContainer` div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `#EditContainer` element is in the root level of the string, so you need to use `filter()`, not `find()`. Try this:

```js
var input = '<div id="container" style="max-width: 310px;">' +
    '<div class="popupheadermap">' +
        '<b>YFC</b>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<input checked="checked" id="tab-1" name="tab-group" type="radio">' +
    '<label for="tab-1">Administration</label>' +
    '<input id="tab-2" name="tab-group" type="radio">' +
    '<label for="tab-2">Information</label>' +
    '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="content-1">' +
            '<td>Id</td>' +
            '<td class="tablerow">1252</td>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="content-2">' +
            '<td>Type</td>' +
            '<td class="tablerow">Gym</td>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>' +
'<div id="EditContainer">' +
    '<button class="editMarker" id="1252"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil editicon"></i>Edit Location</button>' +
'</div>';

var $input = $(input);
$input.filter('#EditContainer').html('<button id="1126_1" class="saveCancel"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o editicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>Save Edit</button><button id="1126_2" class="saveCancel"><i class="fa fa-ban editicon" aria-hidden="true"> </i>Cancel Edit</button>');
$input.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```